# Error: The subfolder for admin templates does not exist or is spelled wrong

Tags: php, scaffolding, fuelphp, scaffold

I have tried to Generate Custom Template using oil Scaffold on FUELPHP.

1. Move `oil/views` in `oil/views/my_custom`
2. run `php oil generate scaffold/my_custom -f monkey name:string description:text`

***the result is***

```
Error: The subfolder for admin templates does not exist or is spelled wrong: my_custom
```

I'm sure admin folder and scaffolding folder available in my_custom folder.

and this is the reference for that 
https://github.com/snrp/fuel/commit/b1f15c2116386ac11639d6a0705ce7607c58c4d1

**Note** 
FuelPHP version is 1.3

any someone know about this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm custom oil fuelphp, maybe can help you with similar issue

check this

https://github.com/viyancs/fuelphp-oil

or upgrade with new version, oil using subdirectory available since version 1.5

https://github.com/fuel/fuel/blob/1.5/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

When you specify an underscore in a folder name that will be treated like a directory seperator, so when you specify `my_custom` it is seaching it this way `my/custom` thats why its unable to find it

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, 

as you know i'm tried using name folder without directory separator and that's still not work same error...

Comment: strange, dont know how much a help out this will be but this maybe will give you more explanation: http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/2881/underscores-in-table-names#Item_2 and i think, posting your issue to the communty form of fuelphp would be way much more effective to give you a more better solution to this issue